# update Query for large number of records

Tags: sql-server

i have an table with 20000  records, now i  need  to update  around 10000  records  with new time stamp value. i have an column with name timestamp

now how can  i update  new  timestamp values for around 10000 records at a  single Query,

any  Solution on this  would be  great

thanks

Comment: Which records exactly need to be updated? Or do you want to arbitrarily update any 10K records?

Comment: Just to point out I doubt 20000 records is a large number or records, on any hardware. SQL Server will handle that in a blink, if not maybe there's something else going on like triggers that should be disabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd use a simple UPDATE statememt.

And you'd have a WHERE clause to restrict to the 10k rows you mentioned.

And you'd have a the new value of course...

I haven't defined @MyFilter here: you can do some thinking for yourself, no?

```
DECLARE @NewValue datetime

SET @NewValue = GETDATE()

UPDATE
   MyTable
SET
   [timestamp] = @NewValue
WHERE
   filtercolumn = @MyFilter --what condition?
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
UPDATE <YourTable>
SET <TimeStampColumn> = <AppropriateValue>
WHERE <YourCriteriaColumn> = <YourCriteria>
```